# Prevent Facebook Sharer See Multiple Images

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I've add og metas to my web site. It works fine.

Only problem is, sharer sees another images too. But I want to show only 1 image. The image that I inserted with og meta.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that Facebook has cached meta data from before you had your og meta data on your page? If so, rumor has it you can trigger a purge of their cash by linting the URL: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/. YMMV

Comment: interesting. I've already tried this (fetch new scrape information) but still showed multiple images. when I fetch it again, it down to one. I tried with another link, again multiple images. fetched second time. boom. so I think I've to wait all my links to be fetched twice(?)